# JQuery Selector for dynamic id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the image source in the Jquery

```
<a href="" class="wanted" id="'.$status_id[$num].'"><img src="/images/wanted.png">
```

through a JQuery selector:

```
$(".wanted "+ id).attr("src", '/images/wanted_.png');
```

Where `id` is defined in the javascript as the php variable `$status_id[$num]`. I first tried using `$(this)` to no avail. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have multiple images inside the `wanted` wrapper? Or do you have multiple `wanted` wrappers with different `id`s? And are you trying to change all of them to a single image? Or just one of them to a single image? Or each of them to a different image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you access `$(".wanted"+id)` , you are actually trying to access an element with the class name = wanted+id. This is because of the '.' before 'wanted'. Also, you seem to be accessing the `<a>` tag directly and setting it's `src` attribute. You need to access the `<img>` tag.
What you could try is this:

```
var x=document.getElementById(id);
$(x).find("img")[0].setAttribute("src","/images/wanted_.png");
```

Comment: Thank you. Elegant and simple.

Answer (score 6):

ID of the HTML elements should be unique across the page.

You can try

```
//I assume id variable is already assigned the id of the element e.g var id = "<?php echo $status_id[$num] ?>";

$("#"+ id).attr("src", '/images/wanted_.png');
```

If you really want to select an element that has the given id and also the class wanted then try this:

```
$("#"+ id + ".wanted ").attr("src", '/images/wanted_.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you have access to the ID when the JS is created, or you don't. If you don't then you'll have to find another way to target the item eg: `$('.wanted')`

If you do, then put it in: `$('#<?php echo $status_id[$num]; ?>')`

Answer (score 0):

Give it another class like `imgToChange`, then use `$(".imgToChange")`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find input value for dynamically loaded elements.

```
$(document).find("#your_input_id").val();
```