# Unable to dynamically set id and check for selection type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check whether the selection is text box or drop down and do actions accordingly. I have the below code:

```
function isSelectOrTextField(id) {
            var element = id;
            if(element.tagName === 'SELECT') {
                var sel = '#' + element 
                alert(  $(sel option :selected).val());
            }
            if(element.tagName === 'INPUT' && element.type === 'text') {
                var tem = $('#' + element).val();
                alert(tem);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I am not able to attach the id dynamically. Normal syntax is like this:

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();
```

Since id  is dynamic i am not sure how to form the syntax. please help

Comment: How do you get id to pass to function??

Comment: may i know why you want to differentiate select from input? coz both the elements supports `$(elem).val()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572569/jquery-selector-for-dynamic-id

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j8Lnt8w4/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use like this:

```
var sel = '#' + element 
alert($(sel).val());
```

The `$(sel).val()` means the value of the dropdown, which means the value of the selected option.

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLSelectElement], I get this error in this line of code  alert($(sel).val());

Comment: I removed '#' and it worked !! Now the code starts like this :                                     function isSelectOrTextField(id) {
                if(id.tagName === 'SELECT') {
                             alert($(id).val());

Comment: Actually, **element** is a keyword also. So change the variable name element to something else. I mean instead of **var element**, use **var elm**, and make the changes accordingly. Else, you can use the **id** as well, like you stated. Also I think your **id** contains the **#** as well from before

Answer (score 1):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function works for both `select` and `input`.

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

So Simply use it.

```
function isSelectOrTextField(id) {
    var tem = $('#' + element).val();
    alert(tem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to retrieve the element itself:

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);
```

Should look more like:

```
 function isSelectOrTextField(id) {
        var element = $('#'+id)[0];
        if(element.tagName === 'SELECT') {

            alert(  $(element).val());
        }
        if(element.tagName === 'INPUT' && element.type === 'text') {
            var tem = $(element).val();
            alert(tem);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Notice that if you're just retrieving the value, jquery is going to handle that for you.